# When and how can pilots waive wake turbulence holds in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, wake-turbulence, holding

According to FAA rules, controllers are required to hold aircraft 2 or 3 minutes for wake turbulence under certain conditions. When is that wake turbulence hold required, and when are pilots allowed to waive it? What is the correct way to request a waiver?

Comment: This on takeoff, I assume. I would also wonder when it is safe to waive the hold.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [AIM 7-3-9](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0703.html) lists the required separations. Behind a heavy aircraft, the departure hold is 3 minutes and it may not be waived. Behind a small aircraft, the hold may be waived on pilot request only:

> 3. Additionally, appropriate time or distance intervals are provided to departing aircraft:
>
> (a) Two minutes or the appropriate 4 or 5 mile radar separation when
>   takeoff behind a heavy/B757 jet will be:
>
> (1) From the same threshold.
>
> (2) On a crossing runway and projected flight paths will cross.
>
> (3) From the threshold of a parallel runway when staggered ahead of
>   that of the adjacent runway by less than 500 feet and when the runways
>   are separated by less than 2,500 feet.
>
> NOTE- Controllers may not reduce or waive these intervals.
>
> b. A 3-minute interval will be provided when a small aircraft will
>   takeoff:
>
> 1. From an intersection on the same runway (same or opposite direction) behind a departing large aircraft,
>
> 2. In the opposite direction on the same runway behind a large aircraft takeoff or low/missed approach.
>
> NOTE- This 3-minute interval may be waived upon specific pilot
>   request.
>
> c. A 3-minute interval will be provided for all aircraft taking off
>   when the operations are as described in subparagraph b1 and 2 above,
>   the preceding aircraft is a heavy/B757 jet, and the operations are on
>   either the same runway or parallel runways separated by less than
>   2,500 feet. Controllers may not reduce or waive this interval.

**EDIT:** The AIM [4-3-10(f)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0403.html) (intersection takeoffs) also addresses this question, including suggested pilot phraseology for waiving the hold (emphasis mine):

> Controllers are required to separate small aircraft (12,500 pounds or
>   less, maximum certificated takeoff weight) departing (same or opposite
>   direction) from an intersection behind a large nonheavy aircraft on
>   the same runway, by ensuring that at least a 3-minute interval exists
>   between the time the preceding large aircraft has taken off and the
>   succeeding small aircraft begins takeoff roll. To inform the pilot of
>   the required 3-minute hold, the controller will state, “Hold for wake
>   turbulence.” If after considering wake turbulence hazards, the pilot
>   feels that a lesser time interval is appropriate, the pilot may
>   request a waiver to the 3-minute interval. **To initiate such a request,
>   simply say “Request waiver to 3-minute interval,” or a similar
>   statement.** Controllers may then issue a takeoff clearance if other
>   traffic permits, since the pilot has accepted the responsibility for
>   wake turbulence separation.

Wake turbulence in general is considered a key safety issue by the FAA and there is a large amount of information in the AIM, the ATC guide and elsewhere.

Comment: As far as required separation goes, they are changing (only at some airports for now) so take a look at: http://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/safo/all_safos/media/2012/SAFO12007.pdf